# Is there a Comment Shortcut/shortcode for links?

Tags: discussion, comments

I think I remember seeing a way to add a text link in a comment similar to when you post a link in a question/answer. I thought it was the same code but it didn't take.

[A Text link][1]
[1] (colon) http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

*This is what I entered in a comment, replacing (colon) with an actual `:`*

Comment: When adding a comment, there should be a *help* link to the bottom right of the text box. If you click it, you get a few markdown tips, included how to format links.

Comment: Jeez, never noticed that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're asking how to enter links in comments, the answer is simply like this:

```
This is [a link](http://url.com)
```

Text in square brackets, then URL in brackets/parenthesis.

```
Your design is flawed because it lacks a [rotating cube](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25059665/CustomerForm.html), for more details see [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11229/is-this-rotating-cube-interface-user-friendly).
```

> Your design is flawed because it lacks a [rotating
>   cube](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25059665/CustomerForm.html),
>   for more details see [this
>   question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11229/is-this-rotating-cube-interface-user-friendly).

---

Works in answers, questions, comments, and chat)

### Super Secret Bonus

You can also add title text to the links by doing the following (also works in comments and chat):

> `[hyperlink](http://example.com "Look at this wonderful title text that pops up when you hover over the link")`

> [hyperlink](http://example.com)

Comment: Example: My answer is flawed because it is not displayed on a [rotating cube](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25059665/CustomerForm.html), for more details see [this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11229/is-this-rotating-cube-interface-user-friendly).

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about this.

Comment: [hyperlink](http://example.com "Look at this wonderful title text that pops up when you hover over the link")

Comment: @JohnB - Nice tip!! I like [that](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com "Thanks for that!")

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, the only secret markdown that works in comments/chat is listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/216955):

> - `[meta]` – link to the current site's Meta; link text is the site name (e.g. "Super User Meta"). Does nothing if the site doesn't
>     have (or already is) a Meta site.
> - `[main]` – like [meta], just the other way around.
> - `[edit]` – link to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalization is
>     respected).
> - `[help]` should be obvious. `[meta-help]` links to "What is meta?" (/help/whats-meta), `[help/on-topic]` links to "What topics can I ask
>     about here?" (/help/on-topic), `[help/dont-ask]` links to "What types
>     of questions should I avoid asking?" (/help/dont-ask),
>     `[help/behavior]` links to "What kind of behavior is expected of
>     users?" (/help/behavior). Link text for all of these is "help center"
>     .
> - `[about]` and `[meta-about]` – equivalent to the FAQ version, but links to the site's About page. Link text is "about"
>     (capitalization is respected).
> - `[so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metaso]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – link to the given site. Link text is the site name.
> - `[chat]` – link to the current site's chat site, the link text being "{site name} Chat".
> - `[ask]`, `[answer]` – link to the "How to Ask" / "How to Answer" page.
> - `[something.se]` – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name. Use `[ubuntu.se]` for
>     Ask Ubuntu.
>
> Except for `[chat]` and `[edit]`, and with the addition of
>   `[chat-faq]`, these also work in chat.

Comment: Thanks John, this is a great resource.

Comment: +1, best answer-to-the-wrong-question ever! :)